# XAMPP Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I've been using this XAMPP for almost 2 years now, never had a problem, but yesterday with no reason apache stoped running whan I turned on my computer here the error I'm getting

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
16:29:46  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:29:46  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:29:46  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:29:46  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:29:46  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
16:29:46  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

mysql works fine (on 3306 port)

I went to Netstat option in XAMMP panel and check if someother programm uses 80 port , but didn't find any thing on my computer uses 80 port,

also I tried changing port to 8080 but also didn't help,

I don't remember that I installed any software on my computer this month, also I deleted skype to check if skype is causing the problem, any suggestions? thanks

do you think updating will help?

Comment: Ive checked error.log but the latest error was 9 days ago, there are no errors related to the problem

Comment: Did you try start apache by cmd manually? generally shows some errors

Comment: do you mean from `services.msc` , it doesn't show much info , it just says `windws could not start the service check system events log`

Comment: No, go to the `apache\bin` by cmd and open `httpd.exe`

Comment: thanks I opened it with cmd and found the error, `httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 555 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file C:/xampp/apps/magento/conf/httpd-prefix.conf: The system cannot find the path specified. Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden Apache could not be started`

Comment: É nois bro :D it's nice this help you to fix.